# ffmpeg android convert yuv420 to rgba can't get a correct video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want convert the video (yuv420) to `rgba`, but I got the following gray video 
after conversion process:

[image]

***My code :***

```
 if (width < 1 || height < 1 || pYUV == NULL || pBGR24 == NULL)
        return false;

//int srcNumBytes,dstNumBytes;
//uint8_t *pSrc,*pDst;
AVPicture pFrameYUV,pFrameBGR;

//pFrameYUV = avpicture_alloc();
//srcNumBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P,width,height);
//pSrc = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * srcNumBytes);
avpicture_fill(&pFrameYUV,pYUV,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,width,height);

//U,V change
uint8_t * ptmp=pFrameYUV.data[1];
pFrameYUV.data[1]=pFrameYUV.data[2];
pFrameYUV.data [2]=ptmp;

//pFrameBGR = avcodec_alloc_frame();
//dstNumBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_BGR24,width,height);
//pDst = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * dstNumBytes);
avpicture_fill(&pFrameBGR,pBGR24,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,width,height);

struct SwsContext* imgCtx = NULL;
imgCtx = sws_getContext(width,height,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,width,height,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,SWS_BILINEAR,0,0,0);

if (imgCtx != NULL){
    sws_scale(imgCtx,pFrameYUV.data,pFrameYUV.linesize,0,height,pFrameBGR.data,pFrameBGR.linesize);
    if(imgCtx){
        sws_freeContext(imgCtx);
        imgCtx = NULL;
    }
    return true;
}
else{
    sws_freeContext(imgCtx);
    imgCtx = NULL;
    return false;
}
```

Can you help me. I have tried some other methods, but didn't work.

Comment: How are you presenting them to the screen? I have a glsl shader that takes the yuv frames as a textures directly. Saves a lot of cpu time converting with swscale.

Comment: thank you very much ,but i need the rgba data to do other things,so the shader maybe not fit me.can't find the problem in our code??

Comment: How did you get `pYUV`? And what the `U, V change` codes do here? btw, could you provide the ffmpeg lib version? Theses approaches seem very old.